# Querying by example using MongoDb, Express in NodeJS is being escaped incorrectly for some reason. I am unable to search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I am working on a generic query method for an API (REST) using nodeJS, MongoDB and Express.

After the routes forward to my module the request, everything works as expected when performing literal queries. I am querying by example, but when I want to query with regular expressions or with 'like' in SQL terms, I am not being able to make it work.

The find method using express inside the module is this:

```
exports.findByQuery = function(req, res) {
   collection.find( req.query).toArray(function(err, docs); 
}
```

This works as expected, except that if I want to query for a field with a regular expression to find say all username that have T, I always get the .query JSON object as a string with "" like this :

```
{"username":"/T/"}
```

instead of :

```
{username:/T/}
```

The req.query is coming from a GET request.

If i replace the:

```
 collection.find( req.query).toArray(function(err, docs);
```

with:

```
 collection.find( {username:/T/} ).toArray(function(err, docs);
```

it works fine!..

I think I need to perform a sanitization or conversion method to req.query before performing the .find on it, but I can't find anything. Any clue or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You'll need to convert the value to a `RegExp` like: `obj.username=new RexExp(obj.username);`

Comment: Thanks!. But what about if I want to be able to be sending a query object who's search criteria is diferent and flexible. Say, maybe next time I want to search for a user's last name, and I want to keep a generic method to be able to search by example. Similar to how you search in Parse.com ? can I say obj = new RegExp(obj) ???

Comment: You'll need to convert any string that is a regular expression to a `RegExp` object. Regular Expressions are only fast in cases where the prefix of the string can be used in the match, otherwise every document must be searched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I wasn't able to convert the objects directly to RegExp as explained in the comments below the quesiton. What I did is create a helper function to return a properly formatted regexp query for mongo, and then perform the .find into it.

So, the find will be:

```
exports.findByQuery = function(req, res) {
    var query = req.query;
    db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
                collection.find( parseRegExpProperties(query) ).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            res.send(docs);
        });
    });
};
```

And here's the : parseRegExpProperties method. I don't know how safe is this, but it's at least a start for me :

```
function parseRegExpProperties(obj) {
   var newObject = {};
   for(var propName in obj) {
      if(typeof(obj[propName]) != "undefined") {
        newObject[propName] = {'$regex': obj[propName], '$options': "i"};
      }
   }
   return newObject;
}
```

If someone has any comment's in regards to performance, or how safe is this, it would be very welcomed!